# Init.d script unable to execute Python script

Tags: python, linux, init.d

I'm currently facing an issue with the init.d script that should execute the Python script. I have ensured about the permissions on the Python file as well as on the init script. Init script is working fine if I replace the Python executable line with just `echo "test" > /tmp/test.txt`.

Python file prints a line and it loops through it for 1000 times.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# /etc/init.d/incapsula-loggrabber
# init script for Incapsula.
# generated by 'myself'.
#
# chkconfig: 345 93 63
# description: Incapsula Logging Script
#

. /etc/init.d/functions

NAME=incapsula-loggrabber
DESC="Incapsula Script to Push logs to Splunk"
PYTHON="/bin/python"
PIDFILE="/var/run/incapsula-loggrabber.pid"
PYTHON_FILE="/root/inittest.py"

do_start() {
     echo Starting Incapsula Script...
     echo $PIDFILE is the file where pid resides
     sudo python $PYTHON_FILE & 
     RETVAL=`echo $?`
     [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/$NAME
}

do_stop() {
    echo $PIDFILE is removed
    kill `cat $PIDFILE`
    RETVAL=`echo $?`
    [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f /var/lock/subsys/$NAME
}

do_status() {
      if [ -e $PIDFILE ]; then
      echo $NAME is running, pid=`cat $PIDFILE`
      else
      echo $NAME is NOT running
      exit 1
      fi
}

case "$1" in 
    start)
       do_start
       ;;
    stop)
       do_stop
       ;;
    restart)
       do_stop
       do_start
       ;;
    status)
       do_status
       ;;
    *)
       echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
esac

exit 0
```

Is there anything I'm missing or needed any modifications to make this init script work?

Comment: What is the actual issue? Any error msg?

Comment: Python script is not executing but I can see the process that is invoked from the init script.

Python script:

import time

f= open("/hfapp/frontend/initest.txt","w+")
for i in range(1000):
     f.write("This is line %d\r\n" % (i+1))
     time.sleep(5)
f.close()

This script should write to the text file but it is not appending as per the script

Comment: How long are you waiting? If it is looping 1000 times and sleeping 5 seconds each time, it will take a while to finish and write out the file

Comment: Also you are not using the PYTHON variable that you've defined

Comment: lxop, I have used the PYTHON variable too earlier but it didn't work. Look at the answer I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved, I have executed the python code in between the backtick such that it will executed first and then later write the process ID to the file under /var/run and also writes the output to the give file as per the python script.

```html
echo `/bin/python /root/inittest.py ` & echo $! > $PIDFILE
```